# retrofit for android - How can i see the path of every request

Tags: android, retrofit

In retrofit there is a interface RequestInterceptor which a class can implement and then in the restadapter you can set this to be the setRequestInterceptor.  an example from the net would be:

```
RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor = new RequestInterceptor() {
    @Override
    public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
        request.addHeader("User-Agent", "Retrofit-Sample-App");
    }
};

RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
    .setEndpoint("https://api.github.com")
    .setRequestInterceptor(requestInterceptor)
    .build();
```

Now for what i need help with.  I was expecting the interceptor to be able to show me all the requests that are going out. Instead its a fascade and just a few methods are exposed. My end goal in retrofit is to be able to print a log of every call that goes out.

Comment: `RestAdapter.setLogLevel`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32514410/logging-with-retrofit-2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the method `setLogLevel(LogLevel.FULL)` on your RestAdapter instance. This will log all retrofit network log.

Comment: actually i wanted to see it from a break point through the request facade.  I already knew about the log lol. But anyway i guess thats the only way, thanks.

Comment: Are you using Retrofit + Okhttp? You can add the interceptor to okhttp. See [this guide](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors)

Comment: the interceptor on Okhttp is exactly what i wanted.i upvoted you.  Excellent. im not sure why someone downvoted me. Its not quite obvious that Okhttp has interceptors.

Comment: @j2emanue this is a community. Accept others and go on. By the way, the upvote on comments are useless :)