# Sending a GET request using retrofit 2 with Rxjava2, Getting Empty Object

Tags: android, retrofit2

> I know a few people have asked this question before, but I have tried those answers. I am new to Android. Everything looks good, but I don't get why I am getting an empty object? Anyone can Guide me about that?

Interface:

```
public interface CryptoAPI {
@GET("ActivityForTestingPurposeOnly/")
io.reactivex.Observable<List<Stream>> getData(@Query("Row") String Row,
                                             @Query("Top") String Top,
                                             @Query("AppID") String appid);
```

This is my retrofit adapter:

```
public class RetrofitAdapter {
   private String BASE_URL = "http://m.ilmkidunya.com/api/sectionactivity/sectionactivity.asmx/"

   public static CryptoAPI newAPICreator() {
       final HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
       interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
       final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                                    .addInterceptor(interceptor)
                                    .build();

       Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
             .client(client)            
             .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
             .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
             .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
             .build();

            return retrofit.create(CryptoAPI.class);
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, the method where I am getting the response:

```
public void getStreams(){
  CryptoAPI.RetrofitAdapter.newAPICreator()
    .getData("0", "20", "73")
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(new Observer<Stream>() {
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(Stream model) {
                arrayList.add(model);                                  
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                               "Size: " + arrayList.size(),
                               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

        }
        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {

        }
    });
}

> here is my 



    @SerializedName("ID")
    @Expose
    private Integer iD;
    @SerializedName("Rating")
    @Expose
    private Integer rating;
    @SerializedName("SectionID")
    @Expose
    private Integer sectionID;
    @SerializedName("ContentID")
    @Expose
    private Integer contentID;
```

[here you can see in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tLsc.png)

Comment: Have you tried hitting the api on Browser or Postman to check whether its really the issue of server?

Comment: `500-Internal Server Error` show that this error is from the server side, not your side.

Comment: yeah i did, I am getting the response accurately.

Comment: solved that issue which was the wrong URL, now getting this error.

Comment: Which sounds like you're expecting an array `[ ... ]` but getting an Object `{ ... }`. Check the JSON you're receiving and adjust your code accordingly.

Comment: Or alternatively, please post an example of the JSON you're receiving from the request.

Comment: bro how i can check the Json i am receving? it is showing exception.  when i change Array to object. error message is String resource ID #0x5

Comment: `how i can check the Json i am receving?` By making the request in Postman, or dump to logcat [using this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32965790/retrofit-2-0-how-to-print-the-full-json-response)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Summary**

I tested the endpoint you gave, and it's working fine

```sh
curl -X GET \
  'http://m.ilmkidunya.com/api/sectionactivity/sectionactivity.asmx/ActivityForTestingPurposeOnly?Row=0&Top=20&AppId=73' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: f64fdf34-4dbb-4201-93e9-e4c95fe7064d' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache'
```

The return is

```
{
    "stream": [
        {
            "ID": 583750,
            "Rating": 0,
            "SectionID": 59,
            "ContentID": 0,
            "SectionName": "Comments",
            "SortOrder": 2,
            "Title": "ICS",
            ...
        }
    ]
}
```

**What went wrong**

You have used `Observable<List<DashboardDs>>`, the `List<T>` class indicates that you are expecting an array as your ROOT json response

**What you need to do**

> **UPDATED (Based on the user's question update)**

Create an object named `Stream` like this

```java
public class Stream {
     @SerializedName("stream")
     List<StreamItem> streamItems; // <-- Array list of the stream items you have
}
```

Create an object named `StreamItem` like this

```java
public class StreamItem {
     @SerializedName("ID") // <- json key
     Int id;
     @SerializedName("Rating")
     Int rating;
     @SerializedName("SectionID") 
     Int sectionId;
     @SerializedName("ContentID")
     Int contentId;
     @SerializedName("SectionName")
     String sectionName;
     @SerializedName("Title")
     String title;
     ... // additional properties you need
}
```

Then change your api service interface like this

```java
io.reactivex.Observable<Stream>
```

In addition, if you're not using rxjava2 with the old rxjava1 or any related `Observable` class, you can just import the `Observable` class directly on the top most part of your service class

```java
import io.reactivex.Observable
```

And use it like this

```java
Observable<Stream>
```

Do it this way, use the `Stream` model object I provided above

```java
public interface CryptoAPI {
@GET("ActivityForTestingPurposeOnly/")
Observable<Stream> getData(@Query("Row") String Row,
                                             @Query("Top") String Top,
                                             @Query("AppID") String appid);
```

This is how you call it

```java
public void getStreams(){
  CryptoAPI.RetrofitAdapter.newAPICreator()
    .getData("0", "20", "73")
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(new Observer<Stream>() {
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(Stream stream) {
               // IMPORTANT NOTE:
               // Items return here in onNext does not mean the 
               // object you have (eg. each Stream's object in streams' list) 
               // it represents streams of generic data objects


               // This is where you can access the streams array
               arrayList.addAll(stream.streamItems) // <- notice the usage

               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                               "Size: " + arrayList.size(),
                               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

        }
        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {

        }
    });
}
```

**Read more on**

- http://square.github.io/retrofit/ (See also how they parse [Github Repos](https://api.github.com/users/joshuadeguzman/repos) with array as a root object on the first example)