# Error cannot resolve method while getting array of object with retrofit

Tags: android, json, list, retrofit

I want to get array of object (JSON) and then get some value.

I have tried done everything like here:
[How to get array of objects with gson/retrofit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34623053/how-to-get-array-of-objects-with-gson-retrofit)

but I am having hint-error from Android Studio like `Cannot resolve method 'getId()'`

**JSON:**

```
[{
    "id": "551454",
    "rights": ["auth", "objects-prepaid-get"],
    "services": [{
        "service_id": "103",
        "options": {
            "sum": 0
        },
        "dismisable": 0
    }],
    "date_activate": "2017-11-11",
    "period": {
        "date_action": "2019-03-29",
        "after": 0
    },
    "ast": {
        "id": "3",
        "services": [{
            "service_id": "4",
            "dismisable": 0
        }, {
            "service_id": "5",
            "dismisable": 0
        }]
    },
    "ast_s": {
        "id": "82",
        "services": [{
            "service_id": "4",
            "dismisable": 0
        }, {
            "service_id": "5",
            "dismisable": 0
        }],
        "date": "2019-03-29",
        "dissmissable": 1
    }
}]
```

**What I am doing in Activity:**

```
onCreate(){
...
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        SomeAPI userClient2  = retrofit.create(SomeAPI.class);
        getUserInfo();

}

private void getUserInfo() {
        token = AppPreferences.getStringFromSh(getApplicationContext());
        Call<List<User>> call2 = userClient2.getInfoUser("Bearer " + token);

        call2.enqueue(new Callback<List<User>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<User>> call, Response<List<User>> response) {
                if (response.code() == 200){
                        id = response.body().getId(); //id - List<Integer>
                        tvAccount.append(" " + id);

                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(UserProfile.this, "Err while loading", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<User>> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(UserProfile.this, "error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

**In interface I have:**

```
@GET("objects")
    Call<List<User>> getInfoUser(@Header("Authorization") String token);
```

**In User.class I have:**

```
public class User {
    private List<Integer> id;
 public List<Integer> getId(){
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(List<Integer> id){
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

**What Is wrong with my code? Where I did a mistake?**

### UPD:

Have tried:

```
            id = response.body().get(0).getId();
            tvAccount.append(" " + id);
```

Getting:

```
Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was StRING at line 1 column 9 path $[0].id
```

Comment: Please, pay attention to updated JSON and info below UPD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `response.body()` returns a `List<User>` so you have to access to one item of the list. example:

```
response.body().get(0).getId();
```

Comment: When I am doing this: `id = response.body().get(0).getId();
                    tvAccount.append(" " + id);` I am getting onFailure() method. But my API returning JSON in those format which I described in my question.

Comment: Show the value of the Throwable on the OnFailure callback and also add your json sample... with for example...two object on the json array...are you sure that your json is not malformed?

Comment: JSON is big and hard but I need only those first id value.

Comment: Oh, and you asked about for two objects in example.. [JSON], [Same JSON structure but another values].

Comment: your model class is wrong, id is a simple String and not list, use this to generate the model class http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Answer (score 0):

you can not get getId() directly from the list

```
List<User> listUser=response.body();
```

if you expect more than one user, you should go through the entire list of users to get the Id's

```
for (User user : listUser) 
{ 
    List<Integer> listIds=user.getId();
}
```

your object must be

```
public class User {
    private String id;

    public String getId(){
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id){
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure that I'm understanding what I need to do in my `onResponse()` and how I should get ID from JSON response