# Retrofit 2 HTTP method annotation is required (e.g., @GET, @POST, etc.)

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

What's wrong with my Retrofit configuration? I'm having this error when I'm adding Basic Authentication with my OkHttpClient but when I used the default client without Interceptor it's working. Or is there something wrong with my Gradle Dependencies..?

```
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    : HTTP method annotation is required (e.g., @GET, @POST, etc.).
            for method APIService.getRegAccrDetails
                    at retrofit.Utils.methodError(Utils.java:177)
                    at retrofit.Utils.methodError(Utils.java:167)
                    at retrofit.RequestFactoryParser.parseMethodAnnotations(RequestFactoryParser.java:135)
                    at retrofit.RequestFactoryParser.parse(RequestFactoryParser.java:59)
                    at retrofit.MethodHandler.create(MethodHandler.java:30)
                    at retrofit.Retrofit.loadMethodHandler(Retrofit.java:151)
                    at retrofit.Retrofit$1.invoke(Retrofit.java:132)
                    at $Proxy0.getRegAccrDetails(Native Method)
                    at alvin.test.myapplication.MainActivity.liferayAccess(MainActivity.java:136)
                    at alvin.test.myapplication.MainActivity.access$000(MainActivity.java:28)
                    at alvin.test.myapplication.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:49)
                    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
                    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
                    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is my API Service to be called

```
  @GET("Triu-services-portlet.regaccrdetails/get-all-reg-accr-details-by-num-branch-code/num/{num}/branch-code/{branch-code}")
    public Observable<List<RegAccrDetails>> getRegAccrDetails(@Path("num") String num, @Path("branch-code")String branchCode);
```

My OkHttpClient Interceptor

```
private static OkHttpClient createOkHttpClient() {
   String username = "test@liferay.com";
   String password = "TEST";
   String credentials = username + ":" + password;
   final String basic =
           "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(credentials.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);//no_wrap



    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    client.interceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Response response = chain.proceed(chain.request());

            Request original = chain.request();

            // Customize the request
            Request request = original.newBuilder()
                    .header("Authorization", basic)
                    .header("Accept", "application/json")
                    //.header("Authorization", "auth-token")//add token for service A4oslsSXZxfbLdk
                    .method(original.method(), original.body())
                    .build();

            response = chain.proceed(request);

            // Customize or return the response
            return response;
        }
    });

   return client;
}
```

Here is my Call for my API

```
private void liferayAccess(){
    Log.d("liferayAccess", "Entered");
    APIService service =  ServiceGenerator.createService(APIService.class);
    Observable<List<RegAccrDetails>> liferayResponse = service.getRegAccrDetails("004589209", "001");

    liferayResponse.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()).map(listResponse -> "response index 0 " + listResponse.get(0).getRegNum())
            .subscribe( response-> Log.d("Liferay Num", response),
                        error -> Log.d("Error", error.toString())
                    );
}
```

> Here is my Gradle Dependencies

```
 compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'

compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.16'
compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:adapter-rxjava:2.0.0-beta2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'

//compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-simplexml:2.0.0-beta2'
/*compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.2.0'*/
compile ('com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta3') {//com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta3
    // exclude Retrofit’s OkHttp peer-dependency module and define your own module import
    //exclude module: 'okhttp'
}
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.0.1'
```

> Here is my App Gradle File

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }




    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "alvin.test.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'

    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.16'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:adapter-rxjava:2.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'

    //compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-simplexml:2.0.0-beta2'
    /*compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.2.0'*/
    compile ('com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta3') {//com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta3
        // exclude Retrofit’s OkHttp peer-dependency module and define your own module import
        //exclude module: 'okhttp'
    }
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.0.1'

    //compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
}
retrolambda {
    jdk "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_20"
}
```

> My Proguard. I also tried add and remove it but same error log happen

```
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep class retrofit.** { *; }
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
@retrofit.http.* <methods>; }
-keepattributes Signature


-keep class com.google.gson.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.inject.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.http.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.james.mime4j.** { *; }
-keep class javax.inject.** { *; }
-keep class retrofit.** { *; }
```

Comment: I don't think you need `.method(original.method(), original.body())`

Comment: i'll try to remove it.. i'm quite new to retrofit..

Comment: Have you set the base path URI? 
If so, make sure you have "/" appended to the end of the URI string.

Comment: i have it at the end of my API_BASE_URL

Comment: @DreamBigAlvin, by chance are you using proguard?

Comment: @siriscac currently i'm not using proguard.. i also saw some post regarding that configuration.. but then i'm not using proguard that's why i'm also confused....

Comment: -keepattributes *Annotation*,Signature
Try adding this in your proguard config

Comment: @DreamBigAlvin I don't think you should be mixing beta2 and beta3 versions of retrofit and its plugins. Besides beta4 is out.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Issue

You're using 2.0.0-beta2 versions of Retrofit plugins which depend on 2.0.0-beta2 version of Retrofit core which still lives in `retrofit` package and at `com.squareup.retrofit` coordinates.

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:adapter-rxjava:2.0.0-beta2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'
```

Then you're importing 2.0.0-beta3 version of Retrofit core which lives in `retrofit2` package and at `com.squareup.retrofit2` coordinates. Basically, it can be used alongside 2.0.0-beta2 or even 1.x version.

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta3'
```

You're not really using 2.0.0-beta3 at all, because it's incompatible with 2.0.0-beta2 plugins and you'd get compile time errors. Check your imports to verify.

What happened is (most likely) you use everything from `retrofit` package except for the `@GET` class which is from `retrofit2` package. Despite their identical name these classes are not the same.

Read more about [why this happened](https://jakewharton.com/java-interoperability-policy-for-major-version-updates/).

#### Solution

Update the dependency and fix your imports.

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0'
```

See [changelog](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md).

Answer (score 45):

### *Using the wrong "@GET"*

This may help someone coming from retrofit1, I was getting this same error and the fix was simple. In my interface I was unaware that I was using @GET from retrofit.http and not @GET from retrofit2.http, changing the annotation from retrofit.http to retrofit2.http was all I needed to do.

[image]

Comment: also for other method types like POST etc, Field and FormUrlEncoded are also needs to be the type of retrofit2.http.

Answer (score 8):

It look like you are using **proguard** and it is stripping annotations.
To get saved from it add this lines to your **proguard-rules.pro**

> ```
> -keepattributes *Annotation*
> -keep class retrofit.** { *; }
> -keepclasseswithmembers class * {
> @retrofit.http.* <methods>; }
> -keepattributes Signature
> ```

if not using proguard make sure that you havn't written something in your app **build.gradle** something like this

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

> Note: Android does not come normally with many of the javax.annotation library by default.

if it is not so then try adding this in your gradle dependency (build.gradle)

```
provided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'
```

Comment: I'm not using proguard and i'm having the error an i also tried to add that but then.. same thing happened..

Comment: @DreamBigAlvin have you checked your build.gradle file

Comment: my minifyEnabled is false so it will not using the proguard.. i also tried implementing it using proguard but same thing happened i added those proguard rules and it's same error logs..

Comment: @DreamBigAlvin have you tried adding the dependency mentioned in my answer

Comment: I meet the same issue.After include your magic code ,it works! It is strange the [official website](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) does not offer this

Answer (score 0):

As Eugen Pechanec stated the problem lies usually in conflict between retrofit and retrofit 2. In my case the error "*HTTP method annotation is required @GET @POST*" was caused by using wrong structure Builder of *HTTPLoggingInterceptor*.

Hence make sure that you are using **okhttp3** with **retrofit2**

So the right structure looks like [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33256827/2163045):

```
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

...

Retrofit provideRetrofit(){

// get base url for endpoint
String endpointUrl = BuildConfig.apiEndpointUrl;

// add logging interceptor
HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(logging).build();

// build retrofit instance
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(endpointUrl)
        .client(client)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
        .build();

return retrofit;
}
```

And the app/build.gradle

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta4'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.0.0-beta4'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta4'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.2.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case everything was perfect except I had imported wrong @POST (while importing by mistakely I created POST annotation in my project), when I removed it, it worked.

So my suggestion is, once check imports properly.