# HTTP method annotation is required Retrofit2

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, kodein

I have an abstraction of usage of repository pattern and I'm not able to do a retrofit call.

I'll go from Retrofit service to my use case.

I've AuthenticationRetrofitService

```
interface AuthenticationRetrofitService {

    @GET(LOGIN_PATH)
    suspend fun doLogin(@Header("Authorization") basicAuth: String) : Either<Throwable, Monitor>

    @GET(LOGOUT_PATH)
    suspend fun doLogout() : Either<Throwable,Unit>

    companion object {
        private const val LOGIN_PATH = "login/"
        private const val LOGOUT_PATH = "logout/"
    }
}
```

Then I have `AuthenticationRetrofitApi` which implements `AuthenticationApi`

```
class AuthenticationRetrofitApi(private val service: AuthenticationRetrofitService) : AuthenticationApi {

    override suspend fun doLogin(basicAuth: String) = service.doLogin(basicAuth)

    override suspend fun doLogout() = service.doLogout()

}
```

Then this is the `AuthenticationApi`

```
interface AuthenticationApi {

    suspend fun doLogin(basicAuth: String) : Either<Throwable, Monitor>
    suspend fun doLogout() : Either<Throwable, Unit>
}
```

Then I have the `AuthenticationRepository`

```
interface AuthenticationRepository {

    suspend fun doLogin(basicAuth: String): Either<Throwable, Monitor>
    suspend fun doLogout(): Either<Throwable, Unit>
}
```

And the `AuthenticationRepositoryImpl`

```
class AuthenticationRepositoryImpl (private val api: AuthenticationApi) : AuthenticationRepository {
    override suspend fun doLogin(basicAuth: String) =
        api.doLogin(basicAuth = basicAuth)
            .fold({
                Either.Left(Throwable())
            },
                {
                    Either.Right(it)
                }
            )

    override suspend fun doLogout() = api.doLogout().fold({Either.Left(Throwable())},{Either.Right(Unit)})

}
```

And from my usecase I call the `AuthenticationRepository` my problem is, I do not know how to link them because if I run the app I get this error.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: HTTP method annotation is required (e.g., @GET, @POST, etc.).

Then I'm using `Kodein` for dependency injection but I do not know what to `bind` or what to `provide` perhaps is that the error? 
Because :

`AuthenticationRetrofitApi` is not used
`AuthenticationRepositoryImpl` is not used

What I'm missing?

### EDIT

This is how I use `Kodein` for my retrofit module

```
val retrofitModule = Kodein.Module("retrofitModule") {

    bind<OkHttpClient>() with singleton {
        OkHttpClient().newBuilder().build()
    }
    bind<Retrofit>() with singleton {
        Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://127.0.0.1/api/")
            .client(instance())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
    }

//I'm not sure if I have to bind this
   bind<AuthenticationRepository>() with singleton {
        instance<Retrofit>().create(AuthenticationRepository::class.java)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share your class where you have Init Retrofit, 
also your DI class

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37243463/11233871 this might can hep you.