# How to see request body in JSON format if Retrofit2 is used while sending POST call to API?

Tags: android, json, retrofit2, androidhttpclient, okhttp

I am sending a POST request to server and my interface is this for Retrofit2 to convert it into JSON

```
public interface LoginService {

@POST("auth/signin")
@FormUrlEncoded
Call<CurrentUser> signin(
        @Field("email") String email,
        @Field("password") String password,
        @Field("device_os") String device_os,
        @Field("device_identity") String device_id
);
```

}

I want to see this request body in JSON format for the purpose of debugging.

Please help ! Thanks in advance .

Comment: try to use `HttpLoggingInterceptor`

Comment: @MD done  Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33256827/1873390)

You can use a [logging interceptor](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-logging-interceptor) for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Interceptor` for `OkHttpClient`, then in the `intercept` method you would have:

```
...
Request.Builder builder = chain.request().newBuilder();
Request request = builder.build();
String bodyString = bodyToString(request);
...

private String bodyToString(final Request request) {
    try {
        final Request copy = request.newBuilder().build();
        final Buffer buffer = new Buffer();

        if (copy.body() != null) {
            copy.body().writeTo(buffer);
            return buffer.readUtf8();
        }

        return "";
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        return "bodyToString error.";
    }
}
```