# Retrofit not getting data from api

Tags: android, retrofit2

I have some api that contains JSON with partner names.

I've set up interface and pojo model. I'll post below my code.

Here is my POJO model Partner:

```
public class Partner {   
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;   
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }    
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Now here is my interface:

```
public interface APIService {    
        @GET("Partner")
        Call<List<Partner>> getPartners();
}
```

And here is my APIHelper:

```
public class APIHelper {

    public static final String PARTNERS_URL = "https://part-of-url.herokuapp.com/partners.json/";

    public static APIService apiService;

    public static APIService getApiService() {
        if (apiService == null) {
            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(PARTNERS_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
            apiService = retrofit.create(APIService.class);
        }
        return apiService;
    }
}
```

And this is Fragment which contains Button where onClick method needs to get data from web.

```
public class DownloadMain extends Fragment implements Callback<Partner> {    
    private static final String TAG = DownloadMain.class.getSimpleName();    
    private Button dloadPartners;
    private Call callPartners;    
    public DownloadMain() {}    
    public DownloadMain newInstance() { return new DownloadMain(); }    

 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.download_main, container, false);

        dloadPartners = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.downloadPartners);
        dloadPartners.setOnClickListener(btnListener);    
        callPartners = APIHelper.getApiService().getPartners();    
        return view;
    }

    Button.OnClickListener btnListener = (new Button.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            callPartners.clone().enqueue(DownloadMain.this);
        }
    });

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) {    
        if(response.body() == null) {
            try {
                response.errorBody().string();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No Partners!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            List<String> partners = (List<String>) response.body();
            Log.d(TAG, "Number of partners received: " + partners.size());
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Partners downloaded!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }    
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call call, Throwable t) {    
    }
}
```

This is all my code for getting Partners from web.

I'm getting this error on server side and can't resolve it:

> No route matches [GET] "/partners.json/Partner"

**QUESTION: Can someone look at this code and say what is wrong and why I'm not getting data from web and also how should I resolve this no route error?**

Comment: Have you asked Internet permission in your manifest ?

Comment: Yes, there is internet permission.

Comment: Have you tried without the clone ? I am a bit septical about what it will do to the call.

Comment: Yes I've tried, clone just allows me to click on button multiple times but still gives me message No Partners! but without clone I can only click once.

Comment: What is the json format your server is returning ? I am thinking you might need to add a POJO like PartnersResponse that contains and deserialize the list of partners.

Comment: It's array of strings like this `[ "partner1", "partner2", ..., "partner200" ]`

Comment: Then your service definition should be @GET("Partner")
        Call<List<String>> getPartners();

Comment: @KevinLEGOFF did it like you said but still getting message "No Partners!".. can't figure what is wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121957/discussion-between-kevin-le-goff-and-unknown19).

Comment: add a `HttpLoggingInterceptor` to see what the error is. look at the answer to this question to see how to implement it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32514410/logging-with-retrofit-2

Comment: The error is `No route matches [GET] "/partners.json/Partner"`

Comment: Then the problem comes from the way youn contact the server. Is partners.json  a file ?

Comment: @KevinLEGOFF It is not a file. It's created form database (rails app) and then with json builder created an json.array where partners names are passing

Comment: Have you tested the endpoint with the url used by retrofit ??

Comment: No I didn't, how should I test this? (I'm pretty new to android)

Comment: When I try your URL in postman I get an no such app webpage. is this the right url? https://part-of-url.herokuapp.com/partners.json/Partner

Comment: @DannyBeaumont This is right url [link](https://ams-biomasa.herokuapp.com/partners.json/)
I've checked it in Postman and it is good

Comment: @Unknown19 That works so remove the partners 'partners.json' from the base url and it to the @GET("partners.json") annotation I think that should fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your get path like so

```
public interface APIService {    
    @GET("partners.json")
    Call<List<Partner>> getPartners();
}
```

and remove that path from your base url.

```
public class APIHelper {

public static final String PARTNERS_URL = "https://part-of-url.herokuapp.com/";

public static APIService apiService;

public static APIService getApiService() {
    if (apiService == null) {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(PARTNERS_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
        apiService = retrofit.create(APIService.class);
    }
    return apiService;
}
}
```

Comment: Done, no errors but also not getting any toast notification I've put in on response method. How should I check if data is downloaded?

Comment: put a break point on if(response.body() == null) then add response.body() to watches and see what you're getting.

Comment: Did like you said but I'm not getting anything... It say that it is connected and nothing happens

Comment: I'm not your pojo is being converted I tried you're response in a pojo generator and got errors I'm retrofit is having a issue reading the response.

Comment: So I need to somehow fix pojo

Comment: So do you have an idea how should pojo look?