# NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lokhttp3/logging/HttpLoggingInterceptor

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

Here are my dependencies,

```
//retrofit and gson dependencies
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
```

and code which uses HttpLoggingInterceptor is like this,

```
 HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(URL)
                        .client(client)
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .build();
```

I have refered to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32514410/logging-with-retrofit-2/36847027#36847027) and for error which I am getting, they said update dependecies version.I have tried all versions of okHttp.logging-Interceptor but still its not working.Can anyone have any idea where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just tested your code, everything seems fine . Please clean your and re-run .

Comment: I dont understand what is the reason behind code is not working in the first place.It wasted my 2 hrs for just showing this exception.Clean project did the work.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just add the same version in all libraries related to Retrofit or change or update the versions.
this problem seems is related to conflict versions.