# Laravel 4 REST API using Retrofit in Android Studio

Tags: android, json, laravel, rest, api

I'm trying to show some list in android using retrofit.

I'm using rest api laravel with url http://ecinema.esy.es/public/kota

the result

```
  [
{
"idKota": "1",
"namaKota": "Yogyakarta",
"flag": "1",
"created_at": "2017-03-12 12:13:43",
"updated_at": "2017-03-12 12:13:43"
},
{
"idKota": "2",
"namaKota": "Jakarta",
"flag": "1",
"created_at": "2017-03-15 11:55:04",
"updated_at": "2017-03-14 07:17:54"
},
{
"idKota": "5",
"namaKota": "Semarang",
"flag": "1",
"created_at": "2017-03-22 08:11:19",
"updated_at": "2017-03-22 08:11:19"
}
]
```

ApiClient

```
public static final String BASE_URL = "http://ecinema.esy.es/public/";
private static Retrofit retrofit = null;
public static Retrofit getClient() {
    if (retrofit==null) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
```

GetKota

```
     @SerializedName("status")
String status;
@SerializedName("result")
List<Kota> listDataKota;
@SerializedName("message")
String message;
public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}
public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}
public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}
public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}
public List<Kota> getListDataKota() {
    return listDataKota;
}
public void setListDataKontak(List<Kota> listDataKota) {
    this.listDataKota = listDataKota;
}
```

ApiInterface

```
@GET("kota")
Call<GetKota> getKota();
```

Adapter

```
List<Kota> mKotaList;

public KotaAdapter(List <Kota> KotaList) {
    mKotaList= KotaList;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View mView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.kota_list, parent, false);
    MyViewHolder mViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(mView);
    return mViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.mTextViewNamaKota.setText(mKotaList.get(position).getNamaKota());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mKotaList.size();
}

public class MyViewHolder extends  RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView mTextViewNamaKota;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mTextViewNamaKota  = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvNamaKota);
    }
}
```

Activity

```
 KotaApiInterface mApiInterface;
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
public static KotaActivity ka;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_kota);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mApiInterface = ApiClient.getClient().create(KotaApiInterface.class);
    ka=this;
    refresh();
}

public void refresh() {
    Call<GetKota> kotaCall = mApiInterface.getKota();
    kotaCall.enqueue(new Callback<GetKota>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<GetKota> call, Response<GetKota>
                response) {
            List<Kota> KotaList = response.body().getListDataKota();
            Log.d("Retrofit Get", "Jumlah data Kota: " +
                    String.valueOf(KotaList.size()));
            mAdapter = new KotaAdapter(KotaList);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<GetKota> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("Retrofit Get", t.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

There's no error but the list shows nothing. I'm new in rest api can somebody help me? sorry for the long code. thanks in advance

Comment: Does your log shows that JSON response?

Comment: @AldrinMathew no, but it shows RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout and Retrofit Get: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $

Comment: Add a logging interceptor to verify your retrofit request and response http://stackoverflow.com/q/32514410/7743702

Comment: `@GET("kota")
Call<List<Kota>> getKota();` change your interface like this and make necessary changes in code

Comment: You're getting this error because what you're actually getting is an array of 'Kota' but you're trying to cast it into an object

Comment: @AldrinMathew cannot resolve setLevel

Comment: What is this class `GetKota`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error is simple:
*"RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout and Retrofit Get: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path "*

It says that your code is expecting an object however what you are getting in Json response is an array of Objects. So what you need to do is serialize it in array of Objects.

Since you have not uploaded the model classes (GetKota and Kota) what i believe your Kota class should look like is

```
public class Kota{

    private String idKota;
    private String namaKota;
    private String flag;
    private String created_at;
    private String updated_at;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return idKota+namaKota+flag+created_at+updated_at;
    }}
```

Try doing something like this in ApiInterface

```
@GET("kota")
Call<List<Kota>> getKota();
```

and get KotaList as

```
List<Kota> KotaList = response.body();
```

Comment: incompatible types on List<Kota> KotaList = response.body(); required: List<com.project.Kota.Kota> found: List<com.project.Kota.GetKota>

Comment: Check your ApiInterface class again

Comment: `@GET("kota")
Call<List<Kota>> getKota();`

Comment: I've changed it to @GET("kota")
    Call<List<GetKota>> getKota();

Comment: what your Get quota class is trying to consume is something like

`{  
   "status":"some status",
   "message":"some message"   "result":[  
      {  
         "idKota":"1",
         "namaKota":"Yogyakarta",
         "flag":"1",
         "created_at":"2017-03-12 12:13:43",
         "updated_at":"2017-03-12 12:13:43"
      },
      {  
         "idKota":"2",
         "namaKota":"Jakarta",
         "flag":"1",
         "created_at":"2017-03-15 11:55:04",
         "updated_at":"2017-03-14 07:17:54"
      }
   ]
}`

Comment: but i dont see that in the response. What you are getting in response is just array of Kota no success or message in Json. All you need to do is change `@GET("kota") Call<List<GetKota>> getKota();` to `@GET("kota") Call<List<Kota>> getKota();`

Comment: There is no need of GetKota class

Comment: thank you i just realised that. but when i changed the getKota to Kota the error RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout stil not solved and the list stil shows nothing

Comment: Try adding an adapter in onCreate 
`@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_kota);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mApiInterface = ApiClient.getClient().create(KotaApiInterface.class);
    ka=this;
    mAdapter = new KotaAdapter(new ArrayList<Kota>());
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    refresh();
}`

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29141729/recyclerview-no-adapter-attached-skipping-layout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29141729/recyclerview-no-adapter-attached-skipping-layout)
This issue is already addressed here

Comment: Thank you so much you saved my life