# How to see what's inside POST-query? Retrofit 2

Tags: android, post, request, retrofit

I made a query to server, but got an error. Please, tell me, how can I look inside my query to see where is the mistake. How do I log the API call in **Retrofit 2**?

Comment: you can't see your query exception from client. See your server log

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32514410/logging-with-retrofit-2

Answer (score 1):

You can log all requests by using Interceptor to Retrofit HttpClient for example you can add HttpInterceptor dependency in OkHttp by following steps in gradle file:

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.0'
```

and then

```
OKHttp client = ....
HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
client.interceptors().add(interceptor);

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("url")
            .client(client) // add custom OkHttp client
```