# Retrofit2: HTTP 404 Not Found

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2

I have this simple service on my server at http://192.168.1.12:8080/api/hooray:

```
router.route('/hooray/')
    .get(function (req, res) {
        res.status(200).send({ result: true, message: "hooray" })
    })
```

It does work from Postman, but from my Android application I unable to reach that url, and I don't know why.

That's the (simplified) code:

### Service's Interface

```
public interface HoorayAPI {
    @GET("hooray/")
    Observable<HoorayResponse> hooray();
}
```

### My custom Response class: HoorayResponse

```
public class HoorayResponse{
    @SerializedName("result")
    @Expose
    private boolean result;

    @SerializedName("message")
    @Expose
    private String message;

    public HoorayResponse(boolean result, String message) {
        this.result = result;
        this.message = message;
    }

    // Getter and setter ...
}
```

### Caller

```
public void foo(){
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://192.168.1.12:8080/api/")
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    HoorayAPI service = retrofit.create(HoorayAPI.class);

    Observable<HoorayResponse> hoorayObservable = service.hooray();

    hoorayObservable
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<HoorayResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {}

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

                @Override
                public void onNext(HoorayResponse response) {
                    System.out.println("Hooray!!!");
                }
            });
}
```

When I call the foo() method, I get this error:

```
retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.HttpException: HTTP 404 Not Found 
    at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.OperatorMapResponseToBodyOrError$1.onNext(OperatorMapResponseToBodyOrError.java:43)
    at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.OperatorMapResponseToBodyOrError$1.onNext(OperatorMapResponseToBodyOrError.java:38)
    at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$RequestArbiter.request(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:173)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$1$1$1.request(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:80)
    at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:211)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$1$1.setProducer(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:76)
    at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:205)
    at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$CallOnSubscribe.call(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:152)
    at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$CallOnSubscribe.call(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:138)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:50)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:8460)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$1.call(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:94)
    at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:272)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:776)
```

I can't figure out because the error: **HTTP 404 Not Found**. That service is reachable and it works. I wrote a service API for *login* in a very similar way to HoorayAPI, with a POST method, and it works. Why it doesn't work here? I mean, the code seems to be correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I've found the answer. The problem was in `.baseUrl(getResources().getString(R.string.url))`. The url was stored in the resource file *values/string.xml* as

```
<string name="url">http://192.168.1.12:8080/api/</string>
```

However, in another resource file *values-**it**/string.xml* there was the following:

```
<string name="url">https://myapp-api.mydomain.io/api</string>
```

Because of the language of my smartphone was set to italian, the resource file *values-it/string.xml* was used, so the program recognized **https://myapp-api.mydomain.io/api** as url instead of http://192.168.1.12:8080/api/.

Be aware to correctly update all the url in the resource files to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the mobile phone is connected to the same LAN ?

Otherwise you can try removing the end slash on the interface but this should not be the problem

```
public interface HoorayAPI {
    @GET("hooray")
    Observable<HoorayResponse> hooray();
}
```

Comment: Yes, the mobile phone is connected to the same LAN, and no, the slash is not the problem :/. As I said, with another service (login) it does work, so this behavior is weird.

Comment: Can I try the service ? If you use ngrok to share your local WS I can try to debug with you.

Comment: Just a curiosity! Have you the same error if you use ngrok url ?

Comment: So I can't debug it. It is very strange, try to reboot the WS! If I get any idea I'll write to you! If you can solve, write the answer please :)

Comment: ok, thank you. I really appreciate it. At least it works on ngrok, for the moment ;P

Comment: I post the answer, I don't know why this behavior. Thank you,if I did not try it with ngrok I would not have been able to solve the problem

Comment: It was a pleasure.
However, I use this to help me in debugging: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33256827/5650222


Try it :)

Answer (score 0):

You should change the type of your `subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())`   to this `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.single())`  It helps for me =)

Comment: This should actually be subscribing on `Schedulers.io()` as this is a blocking operation