# Retrofit Null Response onSuccess Method

Tags: javascript, java, android, node.js, retrofit2

I was following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j7lRiTJ_-cI&t=487s) in YouTube for Retrofit for sending objects in a post request but encounter an error on emulator with a null response **onResponse** method.

**Problem:**
[image: Null Response on Response]

**Main Activity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


private EditText mName, mEmail, mAge, mTopics;
private Button mButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mName = findViewById(R.id.editText);
    mEmail = findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    mAge = findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    mTopics = findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    mButton = findViewById(R.id.button);

    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            User user = new User(
                    mName.getText().toString(),
                    mEmail.getText().toString(),
                    Integer.parseInt(mAge.getText().toString()),
                    mTopics.getText().toString().split(",")
            );

            //Added proof its not a NPE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! 
            Log.d("Main", mName.getText().toString() +
                            mName.getText().toString()+ Integer.parseInt(mAge.getText().toString()) +
                            Integer.parseInt(mAge.getText().toString()) +mTopics.getText().toString().split(","));

            sendNetworkRequest(user);
        }
    });

}

private void sendNetworkRequest(User user) {
    Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://10.0.2.2:3000/api/users/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

    Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();
    UserClient client = retrofit.create(UserClient.class);
    Call<User> call = client.createAccount(user);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Success UserID = "+ response.body(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}
```

}

**Proof of NOT NPE:**

[image: NOT NPE]

**UserClient:**

```
public interface UserClient {

    @POST("api/users")
    Call<User> createAccount(@Body User user);
}
```

**User:**

```
public class User {

private Integer id;
private int age;
private String name, email;
private String [] topics;

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public User(String name, String email, int age,  String[] topics) {
    this.age = age;
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.topics = topics;
}
```

---

**Node.JS**

**App.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const routes = require('./routes/api');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const app = express();

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/user1',  { useMongoClient: true });
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;


app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use('/api', routes);

app.listen(process.env.port || 3000, function(){
    console.log('Using PORT 3000');
});
```

**Api.js:**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const User = require('../models/user');

router.get('/users', function(req, res, next){
    res.send({type: "GET"});
});

router.post('/users', function(req, res, err){
    User.create(req.body).then(function(user){
        res.send(user);
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

**User.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String
    },
    email: {
        type: String
    },
    age: {
        type: Number
    },
    topics: {
        type: String
    }
});

const User = mongoose.model('user', UserSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

**What I have tried:**

- I have tried changing the **BASE_URL** the local ip address of my machine using 'ipconfig' on my terminal. = 'http://192.168.X.X:3000/api/users/'
- Use **Headers and FormURLEncoded** in the **UserClient** = @Headers("Content-Type: application/json") | @FormUrlEncoded.
- Used postman to check responses, which successfully happen.
- Checked Robomongo for verification/

---

**Postman:**

**Get Request**
[image: Get Request]

**Post Request**
[image: Post Request]

**Robomongo**
[image: Robomongo]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BaseURL should be:   `baseUrl("http://10.0.2.2:3000/")` because your `UserClient` interface has the path:

```
@POST("api/users")
Call<User> createAccount(@Body User user);
```

**UPDATE**

Your Topic field should be `String` not `String[]`

Change this:

```
private String [] topics;
```

To this:

```
private String topics;
```

Comment: With this changed it triggered the **onFailure** toast, not sure if working as intended tho

Comment: put the logcat on your question

Comment: There is no error, it executed this = `@Override
        public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }`

Comment: add log to retrofit2 : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32514410/logging-with-retrofit-2

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are doing a bad request?

Try to add a check for null in onResponse() and access the raw response like this response.errorBody.string()

Comment: Added `if (response.body() == null){
                    Log.e("Error",response.code()+"");
                    Log.e("Erro2", response.errorBody().toString());
                    return;
                }` and got `E/Error: 404
 E/Erro2: okhttp3.ResponseBody$1@35d2a64c`