# Is there any way to know the value/structure before sending data while I'm using Retrofit 2

Tags: android, retrofit2

I'm using Retrofit 2, I want to know the values or Structure of sending the value to the server. Is there any way where can I put 'system.out.print' so that I can know what Am I sending?

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32514410/logging-with-retrofit-2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first add this

```
impletemtaion "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:LATEST_VERSION";
```

add this

```
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public OkHttpClient provideClient(Context mContext, CacheInterceptor cacheInterceptor, HeaderInterceptor headerInterceptor) {
        //***************
        HttpLoggingInterceptor logger = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        logger.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        //***************
        return new okhttp3.OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .addInterceptor(logger)
                    .addInterceptor(headerInterceptor)
                    .connectTimeout(Constant.CONNECTTIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .readTimeout(Constant.READTIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .writeTimeout(Constant.WRITETIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .build();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this for HTTPLogging Interceptor for Retrofit 2

https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-log-requests-and-responses