# I could not parse retrofit response

Tags: android, parsing, retrofit2

I have created a common class to access all POJO classes. when i try to parse and acceess POJO variable i am getting null pointer exception. i really do not know where i was wrong . can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

**CommonReponse.java**

```
public class CommonResponse {

private Github github;

public Github getGithub() {
    return github;
}

public void setGithub(Github github) {
    this.github = github;
}}
```

**GithubService.java**

```
public interface GithubService {

@GET("users/{username}")
Call<CommonResponse> getGithubUserInfo(@Path("username") String username);}
```

**Github.java** // POJO

```
public class Github {

@SerializedName("name")

private String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}}
```

**GetUserInfo() // Method**

```
   private void getUserInfo() {
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl("https://api.github.com/")
            .build();

    GithubService githubService = retrofit.create(GithubService.class);
    Call<CommonResponse> call = githubService.getGithubUserInfo(mGitUserName);
    call.enqueue(new retrofit2.Callback<CommonResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<CommonResponse> call, Response<CommonResponse> response) {

            System.out.println("Response:+"+response.body().getGithub().getName());

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<CommonResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            System.out.println("Response error:+"+t.getMessage());

        }
    });}
```

**log**

```
02-19 15:38:53.926 32293-32293/com.ananth.rxandroidwithretrofit E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                              Process: com.ananth.rxandroidwithretrofit, PID: 32293
                                                                              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.ananth.rxandroidwithretrofit.model.Github.getName()' on a null object reference
                                                                                  at com.ananth.rxandroidwithretrofit.ProfileActivity$7.onResponse(ProfileActivity.java:243)
                                                                                  at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:68)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

Comment: CommonResponse is ur pojo class ?

Comment: can you post ur log here >

Comment: https://api.github.com/users/ananth10

Comment: I mean log.. Spelling mistake.

Comment: added log under my question

Comment: My general advice: [log your communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32514410/logging-with-retrofit-2/33256827#33256827) in debug builds

Comment: Have you checked the api response? Is it same as you expected and as per your response model? It is possible that there is a mismatch with response and the response is not able to be parsed with your response model.

Comment: I have created model class based on api reponse. it is working well if i use model class instead of common response class.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `getGitHub` returns `null`. The reason is that the `github` member of the `CommonResponse` instance was not initialized yet when you try to get its `name`. The solution is to modify `getGitHub` this way:

```
public Github getGithub() {
    if (github == null) {
        //Initialize github, so it will not be null
    }
    return github;
}
```

Comment: Thanks you.  Its not getting force close now but i am still get null when i access variable in from pojo class

Comment: @AnanthaBabu I understand. How are you initializing the member in getGithub if it is null in your current version?

Comment: public Github getGithub() { if (github == null) { //Initialize github, so it will not be null github=new Github(); } return github; }

Comment: @AnanthaBabu you are calling the default constructor of GitHub if it did not exist. You will need to set its name somehow, like either calling setName("thename") or implementing a constructor, which expects a String and passing the name to it. Subsequently, this constructor will need to initialize the name of the object to be equal to the parameter you received.

Answer (score 0):

**Initialize your model**

```
Github model; //In your Activity

private void getUserInfo() {
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl("https://api.github.com/")
            .build();

    GithubService githubService = retrofit.create(GithubService.class);
    Call<CommonResponse> call = githubService.getGithubUserInfo(mGitUserName);
    call.enqueue(new retrofit2.Callback<CommonResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<CommonResponse> call, Response<CommonResponse> response) {

            if(response!=null)
            {
            model = response.body(); //Parse your response here
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<CommonResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            System.out.println("Response error:+"+t.getMessage());

        }
    });}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
private void getUserInfo() {
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .baseUrl("https://api.github.com/")
        .build();

GithubService githubService = retrofit.create(GithubService.class);
Call<Github> call = githubService.getGithubUserInfo(mGitUserName);
call.enqueue(new retrofit2.Callback<Github>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<Github> call, Response<Github> response) {

        System.out.println("Response:+"+response.body().getName());

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<Github> call, Throwable t) {
        System.out.println("Response error:+"+t.getMessage());

    }
});}
```

and

```
public interface GithubService {

@GET("users/{username}")
Call<Github> getGithubUserInfo(@Path("username") String username);}
```

Comment: public Github getGithub() {
        if (github == null) {
            //Initialize github, so it will not be null
            github=new Github();
        }
        return github;
    }

Comment: if this https://api.github.com/users/ananth10 is your response, then you will need only a single pojo class(Github), the outer class is not necessary

Comment: Noo. I need a common response class. Please see this class [https://github.com/iammert/AndroidArchitecture/blob/master/app/src/main/java/iammert/com/androidarchitecture/data/remote/model/MoviesResponse.java]. i have just implemented same as it there. but i dont know why its not working

Comment: it depends on the response, in your case you are having a single json object, but in the given example there is an inner json object

Answer (score 0):

Change your POJO classes like that.Do not set getter and setter.

```
public class CommonResponse {
 @SerializedName("github")
 @Expose
 public Github github;
}


public class Github {
 @SerializedName("name")
 @Expose
 public String name;
}
```