# Retrofit Put Request for Mlab

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2, mlab

Hi I'm trying to send a `PUT` request using Retrofit that uses `$addToSet` to my Mlab Server. I can do this using Postman but I'm having trouble doing it using Retrofit.

The collection looks like:

```
[
    {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "5abe74bac2ef1603f4045686"
        },
        "email": "test@gmail.com",
        "completedWalks": [
            "South Leinster Way"
        ],
        "favWalks": []
    }
]
```

The post man request has the API key, Query, and then `$addToSet` is passed in the body as so.
[image: Postman Request]
And the response is:
[image: Postman Response]

I'm trying to do it like this in android.
Retrofit:

```
@PUT("databases/walks/collections/user")
Call<Update> addCompleted (@Query("apiKey") String apiKey,@Query("q") String Email, @Body Update Query);
```

My model:

```
public class Update {

    @SerializedName("n")
    private String n;

    public String getN() {
        return n;
    }

    public Update(String n) {
        this.n = n;
    }
}
```

Creating the update object:

```
String updateComplete = String.format("'$addToSet': {'completedWalks': '%s'}} ", TrailName);
final String query =String.format("{'email': '%s'}",email) ;

final Update queryComplete = new Update(updateComplete);
```

And the Request:

```
Call<Update> completeCall = apiService.addCompleted(mlabAPi, query, queryComplete);
completeCall.enqueue(new Callback<Update>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<Update> call, Response<Update> response) {           
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Walk marked as Complete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<Update> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.e(TAG, t.getMessage());
    }
});
```

But this only overwrites whats in the collection and I have:

```
[
    {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "5abe74bac2ef1603f4045686"
        },
        "n": "'$addToSet': {'completedWalks': 'Kerry Head Cycleway'}} "
    }
]
```

Does anyone know where I'm going wrong, should I not be passing `$addToSet` as a model because it seems to be overwriting all, how do I pass it then?
Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Body Update Query` -- Retrofit will encode the object passed to this as JSON (assuming you are using the Gson converter, which it appears you are).  That is where this `"n": "'$addToSet': {'completedWalks': 'Kerry Head Cycleway'}} "` is coming from.  You need to structure you Java Object the same as your JSON object for gson to serialize it correctly.

I am not familiar with the mlab api, but from your postman, it looks like you want a request body something like this --

```
public class UpdateRequest {
    @SerializedName("$addToSet")
    Map<String, String> addToSet = new HashMap();
}
```

Update your interface to send this object as the body --

```
@PUT("databases/walks/collections/user")
Call<Update> addCompleted (@Query("apiKey") String apiKey,@Query("q") String Email, @Body UpdateRequest Query);
```

And create the request body --

```
UpdateRequest requestBody = new UpdateRequest();
requestBody.addToSet.put("completedWalks", Trailname);
```

and create the call --

```
Call<Update> completeCall = apiService.addCompleted(mlabAPi, query, requestBody);
```

For further debugging, you can see what is actually being sent in your logcat by adding `HttpLoggingInterceptor` to your retrofit instance. 
 See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33256827/1904517) for setup.  Then you can compare what your app is sending vs postman and see where things might be going sideways.