# NullPointerException on Response using Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2

I have got a question. Why I have `NullPointerException`during getting data from **ResponseModel**.

Error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Integer bjd.adrian.retrofitjavapost.ResponseModel.getStatusOfLogin()' on a null object reference
    at bjd.adrian.retrofitjavapost.MainActivity$1.onResponse(MainActivity.java:51)
```

MainActivity:

```
private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void onClick(View view)
{
    EditText usernameET = findViewById(R.id.usernameET);
    EditText passwordET = findViewById(R.id.passwordET);

    String username = usernameET.getText().toString();
    String password = passwordET.getText().toString();

    final RequestModel requestModel = new RequestModel();

    requestModel.setUsername(username);
    requestModel.setPassword(password);

    final Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://192.168.100.9/androidAppScripts/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    WebAPIInterface webAPIInterface = retrofit.create(WebAPIInterface.class);

    webAPIInterface.login(requestModel).enqueue(new Callback<ResponseModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseModel> call, Response<ResponseModel> response) {
            ResponseModel responseModel = response.body();



            Log.v(TAG, "StatusOfLogin = "+responseModel.getStatusOfLogin()+"    ID = "+responseModel.getId());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseModel> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e(TAG, t.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

RequestModel:

```
public class RequestModel
{
    @SerializedName("username")
    private String username;

    @SerializedName("password")
    private String password;

    //getters and setters
}
```

ResponseModel:

```
@SerializedName("statusOfLogin")
@Expose
private Integer statusOfLogin;
@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private Integer id;
```

I am learning how to use retrofit. Please help me !

Comment: can you show your interface WebAPIInterface?

Comment: `public interface WebAPIInterface
{
    @POST("/retrofitLogin.php")
    Call<ResponseModel> login(@Body RequestModel requestModel);
}`

Comment: I think you have an error, so response is not successful, you could check it with response.isSuccessful

Comment: use  if(response.isSuccessful ()) { ... } to verify first if your request was successful. Share log console.

Comment: `V/MainActivity: Response isn't successful !!!`

Comment: What I must to do for repair it ?

Comment: use this to see full log request ().  response.body() is null beacuse you have rror response https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32514410/logging-with-retrofit-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that your link looks like this:

`http://192.168.100.9/androidAppScripts//retrofitLogin.php`.

This results as the concatenation of 
`.baseUrl("http://192.168.100.9/androidAppScripts/")` and
`@POST("/retrofitLogin.php")`.

You should remove the `/` in `.baseUrl("http://192.168.100.9/androidAppScripts/")` or in `@POST("/retrofitLogin.php")`.

I suggest you create a constant `BASE_URL` and store `http://192.168.100.9/androidAppScripts` there and after this use `.baseUrl(BASE_URL)`.

Comment: I delete `/` from WebAPIInterface. It's working ! But I have next error `E/MainActivity: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $`

Comment: How to repair it ? I thought to add code from the php script. Maybe in php script is wrong

Comment: That is a different error.. so a different question. If my answer solved your problem you should accept it so other users will know it's solved.

Comment: Do you know how to repair this error ? Do I make new question ?

Comment: What does the PHP script contain? You can make a new question if you Googled the error and did not find a solution. I suggest you to include details about the PHP script.

Comment: I added php script into question

Comment: @Adrian27045 you should not edit a question that was answered. I think the error you got it's more retaled to php. You're php script should return a valid JSON object. Try to figure it out and if you don't succeed post another question. [Here](https://json.org/example.html) are some JSON examples.