# NoClassDefFoundError: Square Logging Interceptor v3.12.0

Tags: java, android, kotlin, okhttp

## Issue

After adding the [*Square Okhttp Logging Interceptor* library](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-logging-interceptor) to my Kotlin app I am experiencing the following error which I think may be due to a Guava dependency conflict. I've [filed an issue](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/4436) in Square's library as well.

### Error

```
Exception in thread "Timer-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: okhttp3/logging/HttpLoggingInterceptor
    at utils.Retrofit.retrofitBuilder(Retrofit.kt:28)
    at utils.Retrofit.<clinit>(Retrofit.kt:19)
    at content.ContentRequestsKt.getEventRegistryContent(ContentRequests.kt:40)
    at content.Task.retrieveAndSaveContent(ContentTasks.kt:146)
    at content.Task.run(ContentTasks.kt:57)
    at java.base/java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:556)
    at java.base/java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:506)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
... 7 more
```

## Setup

*build.gradle* ([dependency scan](https://scans.gradle.com/s/aolsmwgre4ets/console-log))

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.11'
    ext.junitJupiterVersion  = '5.3.2'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-gradle-plugin:1.0.3'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.2.51'
}

version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"
    testImplementation group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '5.3.2'
    // JUnit Jupiter API and TestEngine implementation
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:${junitJupiterVersion}")
    testRuntime("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:${junitJupiterVersion}")
    testImplementation "org.assertj:assertj-core:3.11.1"
    // To avoid compiler warnings about @API annotations in JUnit code
    testCompileOnly 'org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.12.0'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev206-1.25.0'
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

*Retrofit.kt*

```
package utils

import okhttp3.OkHttpClient
import okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor
import okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory
import utils.Enums.EnvironmentType.PRODUCTION
import utils.EnvironmentType.environmentType

object Retrofit {

    val eventRegistryRetrofit: Retrofit
    val youTubeRetrofit: Retrofit

    init {
        eventRegistryRetrofit = retrofitBuilder(EVENTREGISTRY_BASE_URL)
        youTubeRetrofit = retrofitBuilder(YOUTUBE_BASE_URL)
    }

    /**
     * Build Retrofit object based on source.
     */
    fun retrofitBuilder(baseUrl: String): Retrofit {
        val debugOkHttpClient =
            okhttp3.OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(Level.BASIC)).build()
    return Retrofit.Builder().addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .client(if (environmentType == PRODUCTION) OkHttpClient() else debugOkHttpClient)
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build()
    }
}
```

## Attempted Solutions

1. Rebuilding Jar Artifact.
2. Rebuilding project.
3. Invalidating IntelliJ cache and restarting IDE.
4. Re-syncing Gradle file.
5. Explicitly define **guava** and **com.google.api** libraries.
6. Excluding older versions of **guava** from libraries. ([dependency scan](https://scans.gradle.com/s/qhoyius2oyqew/console-log))

*build.gradle*

```
...
dependencies {
    implementation "com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-jre"
    implementation ("com.google.api:gax:1.33.1") {
        exclude group: "com.google.guava", module: "guava"
    } 
    implementation ("com.google.api:gax-grpc:1.33.1") {
        exclude group: "com.google.guava", module: "guava"
    }
    ...
    implementation ('com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.12.0') {
        exclude group: "com.google.guava", module: "guava"
    }
    ...
}
...
```

Comment: How are you you running this program?

Comment: It's being run in an IDE (IntelliJ) for development and testing. For production it is built into a **Jar** file.

Answer (score 2):

In my case was that I installed **logging-interceptor (3.13.1)**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
        <artifactId>logging-interceptor</artifactId>
        <version>3.13.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Which uses **okhttp (3.13.1)**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
    <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
    <version>3.13.1</version>
</dependency>
```

And my **Retrofit (2.5.0)**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit2</groupId>
    <artifactId>retrofit</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Which uses **okhttp (3.12.0)**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
    <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
    <version>3.12.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Because of the order (or smth.) **okhttp** dependency of **logging-interceptor** got ommited.
I guess **okhttp (3.12.0)** is not compatible with **logging-interceptor (3.13.1)**.

Answer (score 1):

I found the same issue, just adding logging-interceptor to gradle would crash the app.

I've tried different versions: 3.13.1 and 3.14.2 but only 4.0.0-alpha2 seems to be fixing the issue at the moment:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.0.0-alpha02'
```

Comment: Thanks! If this issue arises again I'll test this solution. Please upvote the question so other people with this issue may easily find your solution.