# Problems getting METHOD GET JSON Retrofit

Tags: android, json, get, retrofit2

I am trying to do a GET method that receives a json with retrofit but it is giving me an error. I do not know if it's because I'm not passing the parameter correctly or the Object class is not well defined.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Retrofit retrofit;
    WeatherAPI weatherAPI;
    String locationCurrent = "Barcelona";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://api.apixu.com/v1/")
                .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        weatherAPI =retrofit.create(WeatherAPI.class);
        weatherGET(locationCurrent);

    }
    void weatherGET(final String  location){
        Call<Object> call = weatherAPI.getWeather(location);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Object>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call <Object> call, Response<Object> response) {
                Log.d("%%%%%","Entrada");
                Object dataGETWeather;
                dataGETWeather = response.body();         Log.d("Temp",String.valueOf(dataGETWeather.CurrentObject.getTemp_c()));
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Object> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("%%%%%","Salida");

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Service definition:

```
public interface WeatherAPI {

    @GET("current.json?key=9aa4f8a0b09c4034b44183812191306&q={location}")
    @Headers("Accept:application/json")
    Call<Object> getWeather(@Query("location") String location);

}
```

Object to be received:

```
// The father of the object is this, but it has more subdivisions
public class Object {
    Location LocationObject;
    Current CurrentObject;


    // Getter Methods
    public Location getLocation() {
        return LocationObject;
    }

    public Current getCurrent() {
        return CurrentObject;
    }

    // Setter Methods

    public void setLocation(Location locationObject) {
        this.LocationObject = locationObject;
    }

    public void setCurrent(Current currentObject) {
        this.CurrentObject = currentObject;
    }
}
```

Log of the exception:

```
019-06-14 13:36:36.236 14987-14987/com.example.weatherapiE/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.weatherapi, PID: 14987
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.weatherapi/com.example.weatherapi.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL query string "key=9aa4f8a0b09c4034b44183812191306&q={location}" must not have replace block. For dynamic query parameters use @Query.
    for method WeatherAPI.getWeather
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
```

Answer (score 0):

remove **&q={location}** from end point url

```
@GET("current.json?key=9aa4f8a0b09c4034b44183812191306")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change your `WeatherAPI` interface like so:

```
public interface WeatherAPI {
    @GET("current.json?key=9aa4f8a0b09c4034b44183812191306")
    @Headers("Accept:application/json")
    Call<Object> getWeather(@Query("q") String location);
}
```

Your argument location will be appended to the querystring as "q" (which is what's specified in the `@Query` annotation).

Comment: I just did what you tell me. But the call goes directly to:
 public void onFailure (Call <Object> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d ("%%%%%", "Exit");

            }
        });

Comment: The I would suggest you to add a logger interceptor like so: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33256827/3286819 setting the level to `RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL`. With this you would be able to see the complete request and response in Logcat and be able to determine the reason of the error.

Comment: try to log t.getMessage();

Comment: I do not know if I have done correctly what you tell me, but in the logcat it puts this to me:

HTTP FAILED: java.net.UnknownServiceException: CLEARTEXT communication to api.apixu.com not allowed by network security policy

Comment: Then now your problem is that your API is not secure (not using SSL) and your device is API 23+. Look here for a quick fix: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50834600/3286819 Option 2 is the quickest way to prove this assumption (but I suggest to try to switch your API to HTTPS if possible).

Comment: Okay, now it makes me the response, but object comes to me empty: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'com.example.weatherapi.Current com.example.weatherapi.Object.CurrentObject' on a null object reference

Comment: In the / OkHttp: if you see the whole object, I do not understand why it does not go well

Comment: You should update your question with the information up to this point and the logs you're getting.

Comment: I do the debugger and in response.body () it gives me this:

Response {protocol = h2, code = 200, message =, url = https: //api.apixu.com/v1/current.json? Key = 9aa4f8a0b09c4034b44183812191306 & q = Glasgow}

But then when I equal the answer to the object this one gives me null

Comment: BTW it would be wise to rename your class `Object` to something more meaningful (e.g. `WeatherInfoResponse`), as `Object` may conflict with Java's own `Object` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html (and this could be a quite plausible reason of why parsing is failing).

Comment: Then, again, could you provide the logs you're getting? Please, update your question or share it somewhere else (e.g. pastebin), if you're still unable to update the question because of your current reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Change Your Interface with this

```
    @GET("current.json")
    @Headers("Accept:application/json")
    Call<Object> getWeather(@Query("key") String key,@Query("location") String location);
```