# API keeps returning 401 in android studio but returns ok in browser

Tags: java, android, api, mvvm

I am currently trying to learn MVVM by creating a news app and using the rest API at https://newsapi.org. I am calling the API using retrofit2, but I keep getting a error. I debugged the app by placing a breakpoint at the position where I am suppose to receive the response and the problem is that when I try to make a call to the API in android studio using the API key I always get a 401 error, but when I make the same call in a browser I am successful. Why is this?

Here is my code.

API Interface

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.Query;

public interface ApiInterface {
@GET("top-headlines")
Call<ArrayList<NewsArticles>> getNewsList(@Query("country")String country, @Query("apiKey") String 
apiKey);
}
```

The Repository where I make the call.

```
public class Repository {

public Repository() {
}

static final String BASE_URL = "https://newsapi.org/v2/";

MutableLiveData<ArrayList<NewsArticles>> newsArticleList = new MutableLiveData<>();

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .setLenient()
        .create();

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
        .build();

ApiInterface apiInterface = retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);

Call<ArrayList<NewsArticles>> call = apiInterface.getNewsList("us","api");

public MutableLiveData<ArrayList<NewsArticles>> getCall() {
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<NewsArticles>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<NewsArticles>> call, Response<ArrayList<NewsArticles>> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                newsArticleList.setValue(response.body());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList<NewsArticles>> call, Throwable t) {
          t.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    return newsArticleList;
}


}
```

Comment: Try to enable the Logging https://stackoverflow.com/a/33256827/6291068
And attach here the complete request and response.
It will help us to help you :D

Comment: @HugoLandim I tried logging it but the logcat remains empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explicitly specifying your headers in the API Interface should work.

```
public interface ApiInterface {
   @Headers(
        value = [
            "Accept: application/json",
            "Content-type:application/json"]
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, tried this but it still does not work. This is what the debugger shows me: Response{protocol=h2, code=401, message=, url=https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us}

Comment: Did you run it on localhost? `{Requests from the browser are not allowed on the Developer plan, except from localhost."}`

Comment: Thanks man, I didn't know that you couldn't  make  a call outside  of the localhost before. Sorry if it feels like  I wasted your time, but  this is my first  time really  using  an api so I didn't  really know  about  localhost before you bought it up. I think I will use another api instead  then. Thanks.

Comment: You can try this api: https://open-api.xyz/placeholder/blogs

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is an issue with the http headers you provide on both cases.

Try to debug by sniffing the http protocol data, and compare the two. See what you are missing...