# Why retrofit returns null in response body?

Tags: kotlin, repository, retrofit, dagger-hilt

Get `null` response results in response body. Using retrofit, dagger and repository. Why get `null` in response I don't know. My model seem right. Whats the problem?

MainViewModel.kt

```
@HiltViewModel
class MainViewModel@Inject constructor(
    private val repository: MovieRepository,
    @ApplicationContext private val context: Context
) : ViewModel() {

    val movieList = MutableLiveData<Resource<Movie>>()

    fun getAllMovies(movieName: String) {
        movieList.postValue(Resource.Loading())
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                if (hasInternetConnection(context)) {
                    val response = repository.getMovies(movieName, "ffe9123f")
                    movieList.postValue(Resource.Success(response.body()!!))
                } else
                    movieList.postValue(Resource.Error("Internet yok"))
            } catch (ex: Exception) {
                when (ex) {
                    is IOException -> movieList.postValue(Resource.Error("Network Failure " + ex.localizedMessage))
                    else -> movieList.postValue(Resource.Error("Conversion Error"))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Resource.kt

```
sealed class Resource<T>(
    val data: T? = null,
    val message: String? = null
) {
    class Success<T>(data: T): Resource<T>(data)
    class Error<T>(message: String, data: T? = null): Resource<T>(data, message)
    class Loading<T> : Resource<T>()
}
```

MovieRepository.kt

```
@Singleton
class MovieRepository @Inject constructor(private val movieAppService: MovieAppService) {

    suspend fun getMovies(title: String, aKey: String): Response<Movie> = withContext(
        Dispatchers.IO
    ) {
        val movies = movieAppService.getMovies(title = title, aKey = aKey)
        movies
    }
```

Movie.kt

```
data class Movie(
    val title: String,
    val year: String,
    val rated: String,
    val released: String,
    val runtime: String,
    val genre: String,
    val director: String,
    val writer: String,
    val actors: String,
    val plot: String,
    val language: String,
    val country: String,
    val awards: String,
    val poster: String,
    val ratings: List<Rating>,
    val metascore: String,
    val imdbRating: String,
    val imdbVotes: String,
    val imdbID: String,
    val type: String,
    val dvd: String,
    val boxOffice: String,
    val production: String,
    val website: String,
    val response: String
)
```

MovieAppService.kt

```
interface MovieAppService {
    companion object {
        const val ENDPOINT = "http://www.omdbapi.com/"
    }

    @GET(".")
    suspend fun getMovies(@Query("t") title: String,@Query("apikey") aKey: String): Response<Movie>
}

{"Title":"A Beautiful Mind","Year":"2001","Rated":"PG-13","Released":"04 Jan 2002","Runtime":"135 min","Genre":"Biography, Drama","Director":"Ron Howard","Writer":"Akiva Goldsman, Sylvia Nasar","Actors":"Russell Crowe, Ed Harris, Jennifer Connelly","Plot":"After John Nash, a brilliant but asocial mathematician, accepts secret work in cryptography, his life takes a turn for the nightmarish.","Language":"English","Country":"United States","Awards":"Won 4 Oscars. 37 wins & 69 nominations total","Poster":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMzcwYWFkYzktZjAzNC00OGY1LWI4YTgtNzc5MzVjMDVmNjY0XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTQxNzMzNDI@._V1_SX300.jpg","Ratings":[{"Source":"Internet Movie Database","Value":"8.2/10"},{"Source":"Rotten Tomatoes","Value":"74%"},{"Source":"Metacritic","Value":"72/100"}],"Metascore":"72","imdbRating":"8.2","imdbVotes":"908,920","imdbID":"tt0268978","Type":"movie","DVD":"25 Jun 2002","BoxOffice":"$170,742,341","Production":"N/A","Website":"N/A","Response":"True"}
```

Comment: It is difficult to answer your question without actually observing the interaction, adding a logger (as described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32514410/logging-with-retrofit-2 for example) would help.

Comment: I know thats hard. I solved it. I will post answer. But thanks for your reply. I will use logger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Movie model is wrong. I didn't realize the starting letter is uppercase letter.

Movie.kt

```
data class Movie(
    val Title: String,
    val Year: String,
    val Rated: String,
    val Released: String,
    val Runtime: String,
    val Genre: String,
    val Director: String,
    val Writer: String,
    val Actors: String,
    val Plot: String,
    val Language: String,
    val Country: String,
    val Awards: String,
    val Poster: String,
    val Ratings: List<Rating>,
    val Metascore: String,
    val imdbRating: String,
    val imdbVotes: String,
    val imdbID: String,
    val Type: String,
    val Dvd: String,
    val boxOffice: String,
    val Production: String,
    val Website: String,
    val Response: String
)
```