# Connect Kotlin Retrofit with Nodejs Server

Tags: android, node.js, kotlin, android-recyclerview, retrofit

I’m trying to connect my Koltin project to the Nodejs backend server using Retrofit but I get a white blank screen whenever I run the mobile app
[image: Blank white screen]

here is my Adapter code

```
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.AsyncListDiffer
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DiffUtil
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import tn.esprit.t1.databinding.ItemCatastropheBinding
import tn.esprit.t1.model.Catastrophe

class CatastropheAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<CatastropheAdapter.CatastropheViewHolder>() {
    inner class CatastropheViewHolder(val binding: ItemCatastropheBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)

    private val diffCallback = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Catastrophe>(){
        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Catastrophe, newItem: Catastrophe): Boolean {
           return oldItem._id == newItem._id
        }

        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Catastrophe, newItem: Catastrophe): Boolean {
        return oldItem==newItem
        }
    }

    private val differ = AsyncListDiffer(this, diffCallback)

    var catastrophes: List<Catastrophe>
        get() = differ.currentList
        set(value) { differ.submitList(value)}

    override fun getItemCount()= catastrophes.size

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CatastropheViewHolder {
        return CatastropheViewHolder(ItemCatastropheBinding.inflate(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
            parent,
            false
        ))
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CatastropheViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.binding.apply {
            val catastrophe = catastrophes[position]
            tvType.text = catastrophe.type
            tvPlace.text = catastrophe.description
            tvMag.text = catastrophe.magnitude.toString()
        }
    }
}
```

I want to display 3 text views on my recycler view ( Type, description, magnitude )

here is my class code

```
data class Catastrophe(
    val _id: Id,
    val titre: String,
    val type: String,
    val tsunami: Int,
    val description: String,
    val date: Date,
    val radius: Double,
    val magnitude: Double,
    val latitudeDeCatastrophe: Double,
    val longitudeDeCatastrophe: Double,
    val createdAt: Date,
    val updatedAt: Date
)
```

CatastropheAPI

```
interface CatastropheApi {

    @GET("catastrophe/")
    suspend fun getCatastophes(): Response<List<Catastrophe>>
}
```

and this is my retrofit instance code

```
package tn.esprit.t1.repository

import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory
import retrofit2.create

object RetrofitInstance {
    val api: CatastropheApi by lazy {
        Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://192.168.1.105:9090/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
            .create(CatastropheApi::class.java)
    }
}
```

and finally my main activity

```
package tn.esprit.t1

import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.core.view.isVisible
import androidx.lifecycle.lifecycleScope
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import retrofit2.HttpException
import retrofit2.http.HTTP
import retrofit2.http.Tag
import tn.esprit.t1.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import tn.esprit.t1.repository.CatastropheAdapter
import tn.esprit.t1.repository.RetrofitInstance
import tn.esprit.t1.ui.theme.T1Theme
import java.io.IOException

const val TAG = "Main Activity"

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    private lateinit var catastropheAdapter: CatastropheAdapter

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        setupRecyclerView()

        lifecycleScope.launch {
            binding.progressBar.isVisible = true

            val  response = try {
                RetrofitInstance.api.getCatastophes()
            }
            catch (e:IOException) {
                Log.e(TAG, "IO Exception, No Internet Connection")
                binding.progressBar.isVisible = false
                return@launch
            }
            catch (e: HttpException) {
                Log.e(TAG, "HttpException, no INternet ")
                binding.progressBar.isVisible = false
                return@launch
            }
            if (response.isSuccessful && response.body() != null)
            {
                catastropheAdapter.catastrophes = response.body()!!
            }
            else
            {
                Log.e(TAG, "Response not successful" )
            }
            binding.progressBar.isVisible = false
        }
    }
    private fun setupRecyclerView() = binding.rvCatastrophe.apply {
        catastropheAdapter = CatastropheAdapter()
        adapter = catastropheAdapter
        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)
    }
}
```

this is the logcat

```
2023-11-07 15:00:52.245 11969-11969 tn.esprit.t1            tn.esprit.t1                         I  Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2023-11-07 15:00:56.107 11969-11969 tn.esprit.t1            tn.esprit.t1                         W  Unexpected CPU variant for x86: x86_64.
                                                                                                    Known variants: atom, sandybridge, silvermont, kabylake, default
2023-11-07 15:00:57.314 11969-11969 re-initialized>         tn.esprit.t1                         W  type=1400 audit(0.0:71): avc: granted { execute } for path="/data/data/tn.esprit.t1/code_cache/startup_agents/3dfe4a80-agent.so" dev="dm-33" ino=147461 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c159,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c159,c256,c512,c768 tclass=file app=tn.esprit.t1
2023-11-07 15:00:58.071 11969-11969 tn.esprit.t1            tn.esprit.t1                         W  DexFile /data/data/tn.esprit.t1/code_cache/.studio/instruments-181d6ec9.jar is in boot class path but is not in a known location
2023-11-07 15:00:58.222 11969-11969 tn.esprit.t1            tn.esprit.t1                         W  Redefining intrinsic method java.lang.Thread java.lang.Thread.currentThread(). This may cause the unexpected use of the original definition of java.lang.Thread java.lang.Thread.currentThread()in methods that have already been compiled.
2023-11-07 15:00:58.223 11969-11969 tn.esprit.t1            tn.esprit.t1                         W  Redefining intrinsic method boolean java.lang.Thread.interrupted(). This may cause the unexpected use of the original definition of boolean java.lang.Thread.interrupted()in methods that have already been compiled.
2023-11-07 15:00:58.242 11969-11969 Compatibil...geReporter tn.esprit.t1                         D  Compat change id reported: 171979766; UID 10159; state: ENABLED
2023-11-07 15:00:58.399 11969-11969 ziparchive              tn.esprit.t1                         W  Unable to open '/data/data/tn.esprit.t1/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes6.dm': No such file or directory
2023-11-07 15:00:58.400 11969-11969 ziparchive              tn.esprit.t1                         W  Unable to open '/data/app/~~GzDAPB5FTK6m4UOLjcK8TQ==/tn.esprit.t1-Sa28IPLd8ND7KFP4kRHMBg==/base.dm': No such file or directory
2023-11-07 15:00:58.401 11969-11969 ziparchive              tn.esprit.t1                         W  Unable to open '/data/app/~~GzDAPB5FTK6m4UOLjcK8TQ==/tn.esprit.t1-Sa28IPLd8ND7KFP4kRHMBg==/base.dm': No such file or directory
2023-11-07 15:01:03.350 11969-11969 nativeloader            tn.esprit.t1                         D  Configuring classloader-namespace for other apk /data/app/~~GzDAPB5FTK6m4UOLjcK8TQ==/tn.esprit.t1-Sa28IPLd8ND7KFP4kRHMBg==/base.apk. target_sdk_version=33, uses_libraries=, library_path=/data/app/~~GzDAPB5FTK6m4UOLjcK8TQ==/tn.esprit.t1-Sa28IPLd8ND7KFP4kRHMBg==/lib/x86_64, permitted_path=/data:/mnt/expand:/data/user/0/tn.esprit.t1
2023-11-07 15:01:03.392 11969-11969 GraphicsEnvironment     tn.esprit.t1                         V  ANGLE Developer option for 'tn.esprit.t1' set to: 'default'
2023-11-07 15:01:03.393 11969-11969 GraphicsEnvironment     tn.esprit.t1                         V  ANGLE GameManagerService for tn.esprit.t1: false
2023-11-07 15:01:03.395 11969-11969 GraphicsEnvironment     tn.esprit.t1                         V  Neither updatable production driver nor prerelease driver is supported.
2023-11-07 15:01:03.405 11969-11969 NetworkSecurityConfig   tn.esprit.t1                         D  No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2023-11-07 15:01:03.410 11969-11969 NetworkSecurityConfig   tn.esprit.t1                         D  No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2023-11-07 15:01:03.485 11969-12078 libEGL                  tn.esprit.t1                         D  loaded /vendor/lib64/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
2023-11-07 15:01:03.496 11969-12078 libEGL                  tn.esprit.t1                         D  loaded /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
2023-11-07 15:01:03.503 11969-12078 libEGL                  tn.esprit.t1                         D  loaded /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
2023-11-07 15:01:03.797 11969-11969 tn.esprit.t1            tn.esprit.t1                         W  Accessing hidden method Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;-><init>(Ljava/lang/Class;I)V (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
2023-11-07 15:01:03.869 11969-11969 tn.esprit.t1            tn.esprit.t1                         W  Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->get()Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard; (unsupported,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)
2023-11-07 15:01:03.869 11969-11969 tn.esprit.t1            tn.esprit.t1                         W  Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->open(Ljava/lang/String;)V (unsupported,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)
2023-11-07 15:01:03.869 11969-11969 tn.esprit.t1            tn.esprit.t1                         W  Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->warnIfOpen()V (unsupported,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)
2023-11-07 15:01:04.067 11969-11969 Choreographer           tn.esprit.t1                         I  Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2023-11-07 15:01:04.123 11969-12076 HostConnection          tn.esprit.t1                         D  createUnique: call
2023-11-07 15:01:04.124 11969-12076 HostConnection          tn.esprit.t1                         D  HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x70a0c8c49650, tid 12076
2023-11-07 15:01:04.419 11969-12076 HostConnection          tn.esprit.t1                         D  HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_has_shared_slots_host_memory_allocator ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_queue_submit_with_commands ANDROID_EMU_sync_buffer_data ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_qsri ANDROID_EMU_read_color_buffer_dma ANDROID_EMU_hwc_multi_configs GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2 
2023-11-07 15:01:04.422 11969-12076 OpenGLRenderer          tn.esprit.t1                         W  Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
2023-11-07 15:01:04.422 11969-12076 OpenGLRenderer          tn.esprit.t1                         W  Failed to initialize 101010-2 format, error = EGL_SUCCESS
2023-11-07 15:01:04.459 11969-12076 EGL_emulation           tn.esprit.t1                         D  eglCreateContext: 0x70a0c8c49dd0: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
2023-11-07 15:01:04.472 11969-12076 EGL_emulation           tn.esprit.t1                         D  eglMakeCurrent: 0x70a0c8c49dd0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x70a2ec000080) (first time)
2023-11-07 15:01:04.550 11969-12076 Gralloc4                tn.esprit.t1                         I  mapper 4.x is not supported
2023-11-07 15:01:04.555 11969-12076 HostConnection          tn.esprit.t1                         D  createUnique: call
2023-11-07 15:01:04.556 11969-12076 HostConnection          tn.esprit.t1                         D  HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x70a0c8c49110, tid 12076
2023-11-07 15:01:04.557 11969-12076 goldfish-address-space  tn.esprit.t1                         D  allocate: Ask for block of size 0x100
2023-11-07 15:01:04.557 11969-12076 goldfish-address-space  tn.esprit.t1                         D  allocate: ioctl allocate returned offset 0x3f3ffe000 size 0x2000
2023-11-07 15:01:04.581 11969-12076 Gralloc4                tn.esprit.t1                         W  allocator 4.x is not supported
2023-11-07 15:01:04.751 11969-12076 HostConnection          tn.esprit.t1                         D  HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_has_shared_slots_host_memory_allocator ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_queue_submit_with_commands ANDROID_EMU_sync_buffer_data ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_qsri ANDROID_EMU_read_color_buffer_dma ANDROID_EMU_hwc_multi_configs GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2 
2023-11-07 15:01:04.973 11969-12076 Parcel                  tn.esprit.t1                         W  Expecting binder but got null!
2023-11-07 15:01:04.974 11969-11969 Main Activity           tn.esprit.t1                         E  IO Exception, No Internet Connection
2023-11-07 15:01:04.985 11969-12007 OpenGLRenderer          tn.esprit.t1                         I  Davey! duration=1508ms; Flags=1, FrameTimelineVsyncId=38161, IntendedVsync=3403246544664, Vsync=3403846544640, InputEventId=0, HandleInputStart=3403855290100, AnimationStart=3403855305500, PerformTraversalsStart=3403855506400, DrawStart=3404540491200, FrameDeadline=3403263211330, FrameInterval=3403854704700, FrameStartTime=16666666, SyncQueued=3404549624100, SyncStart=3404552560300, IssueDrawCommandsStart=3404559417500, SwapBuffers=3404740054900, FrameCompleted=3404757783500, DequeueBufferDuration=21400, QueueBufferDuration=211400, GpuCompleted=3404757340000, SwapBuffersCompleted=3404757783500, DisplayPresentTime=0, CommandSubmissionCompleted=3404740054900, 
2023-11-07 15:01:09.235 11969-12192 ProfileInstaller        tn.esprit.t1                         D  Installing profile for tn.esprit.t1
2023-11-07 15:01:26.174 11969-12004 System                  tn.esprit.t1                         W  A resource failed to call close.
```

Comment: Mention `CatastropheApi ` class code in the question.

Comment: hey @KamalNayan.. it's done, where do you think the problem is?

Comment: let me see the updated question

Comment: I tried to hit the endpoint and this is unreachable. Are you sure that the endpoint is correct ?

Comment: @KamalNayan this is the url i'm using on postman to test and it's working correctly "http://localhost:9090/catastrophe/", on kotlin you have to change localhost with your ip adress, it's "192.168.1.105" for me

Comment: okay then kindly share the logcat output

Comment: where can I send it to you ? because I can't put it in the comment section.. it exceeds the maximum characters allowed

Comment: you can take screenshot and put it here or in the question.

Comment: You can find the logcat on the question section

Comment: I couldn't find any helpful message. Are you sure that the connection with your local host is successful.

Comment: yes, when I test the endpoint with postman, it's working correctly

Comment: you can use `OkHttp Interceptor` or `Pluto` library to monitor your api calls. Like what is the api call request body and response body.

Comment: I can understand that postman is working fine, I'm asking in context of from your device (phone / emulator )

Comment: You can follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32514410/logging-with-retrofit-2 to add network logging

Comment: @KamalNayan how can I check this ?

Comment: Add network logging, just 5-7 lines of code. Above I have mentioned a link.  (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32514410/logging-with-retrofit-2)

Comment: Also I'm assuming that you have this permission mentioned in your manifest.xml file  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Comment: @KamalNayan yes ofc. I've already added permissions on AndroidManifest.xml, I'll try adding the network logging code

Comment: I was just making sure, we should not work based on assumptions 

Comment: no worries, thank you for the help Kamal. I'll add the network logging code and I'll tell what happened

Comment: sure, let me know if you need any help.

Comment: @KamalNayan I store the data on mongodb database not locally on nodejs server project and that's what causing the problem I think, what do I have to do?

Comment: May be I'm not sure like if the data is on mongo db but the api you are hitting locally is working fine, then it means that we should check android side.

Comment: Have you added network logging?

Comment: yes, I tried to test my application with this endpoint "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos" and It worked coorectly

Comment: ohh then it might be the issue.